# WebViewJavascriptBridge Unexpected token var line:1 error for android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm using WebViewJavascriptBridge link [here](https://github.com/fangj/WebViewJavascriptBridge/tree/master/Android/WebViewJavascriptBridge). It gives me always error that

```
D/test: user_client.js called! line:1
D/test: onPageFinished
D/test: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var line:1
```

Please check the last line, it gives error.